# ejabberd LDAP auth and vcard access works, but search does not - why?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ejabberd

I've set up an ejabberd installation and configured the LDAP authentication and vcard data extraction against an ActiveDirectory global catalog server as described in the documentation. This part works - I can logon to the server using my AD user, I can add other users if I know their AD name. What doesn't work is the search function - I can access the buddy search service, I get the search form with the fields that were configured, but the search never returns any results. Turning up the log level, I can see that the LDAP query goes out and is answered, but apparently an empty result set is sent to the client. How can I find out what might be going wrong here?

Comment: What does your search base look like on the LDAP config?

Comment: @Cole It's a multi-domain config, but nothing fancy - `{ldap_base, "dc=site,dc=mycompany,dc=de"}` for each `host_config`. As I wrote, I can see that the correct LDAP results for the query come in...